# How to install vue and setup vue on laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to start a new laravel project with vue, and later on element-ui and inertia. I did `laravel new <name>` in the terminal in the location I wanted `C:/xampp/htdocs` then I opened it up in PhpStorm and did `composer install` and `npm install`. The tutorials I've seen do this and vue is already there, but not for me. In `resources/js` there is only `app.js` and `bootstrap.js`, when they show this folder in the tutorials it has another folder called `components` with an `ExampleComponent.vue` inside.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you are using Laravel below 6.X,

1. choose the frontend scaffolding preset with `php artisan preset vue`
2. install the required npm packages with `npm install`
3. run the first build to get the frontend looking good with `npm run dev`

#### Or if you are using Laravel 6.X

1. get the scaffolders with `composer require laravel/ui`
2. choose the frontend scaffolding preset with `php artisan ui vue`
3. install the required npm packages with `npm install`
4. run the first build to get the frontend looking good with `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

Bash script for deploy Laravel 10 + Vue 3.

Turnkey deployment with fixed versions.

Can be used as the basis of a Docker deployment script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#######################
### laravel install ###
#######################

version_laravel="^10.3"
version_vue="3.4.15"
version_vue_loader="17.4.2"
version_webpack="5.90.1"
version_laravel_mix="6.0.49"
version_vitejs_vue="5.0.3"

cd "../$(dirname "$0")"
echo "COMMAND 'composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel':"
               composer create-project laravel/laravel=$version_laravel laravel
php laravel/artisan --version

echo "COMMAND 'mv laravel/* .':"  && mv    laravel/* .
echo "COMMAND 'mv laravel/.* .':" && mv    laravel/.* .
echo "COMMAND 'rmdir laravel':"   && rmdir laravel

###################
### npm install ###
###################

echo "COMMAND 'npm install':"             && npm install
echo "VERSION INSTALLED:"                 && npm -v

echo "COMMAND 'npm install vue':"         && npm install vue@$version_vue --save-dev
echo "VERSION AVAILABLE:"                 && npm info vue version
echo "VERSION INSTALLED:"                 && npm list --depth=0 | grep "vue@" | sed "s/├── //g" | sed "s/└── //g" | sed "s/vue@//g"

echo "COMMAND 'npm install vue-loader':"  && npm install vue-loader@$version_vue_loader --save-dev
echo "VERSION AVAILABLE:"                 && npm info vue-loader version
echo "VERSION INSTALLED:"                 && npm list --depth=0 | grep "vue-loader@" | sed "s/├── //g" | sed "s/└── //g" | sed "s/vue-loader@//g"

echo "COMMAND 'npm install webpack':"     && npm install webpack@$version_webpack --save-dev
echo "VERSION AVAILABLE:"                 && npm info webpack version
echo "VERSION INSTALLED:"                 && npm list --depth=0 | grep "webpack@" | sed "s/├── //g" | sed "s/└── //g" | sed "s/webpack@//g"

echo "COMMAND 'npm install laravel-mix':" && npm install laravel-mix@$version_laravel_mix --save-dev
echo "VERSION AVAILABLE:"                 && npm info laravel-mix version
echo "VERSION INSTALLED:"                 && npm list --depth=0 | grep "laravel-mix@" | sed "s/├── //g" | sed "s/└── //g" | sed "s/laravel-mix@//g"

echo "COMMAND 'npm install plugin-vue':"  && npm install @vitejs/plugin-vue@$version_vitejs_vue --save-dev
echo "VERSION AVAILABLE:"                 && npm info @vitejs/plugin-vue version
echo "VERSION INSTALLED:"                 && npm list --depth=0 | grep "@vitejs/plugin-vue@" | sed "s/├── //g" | sed "s/└── //g" | sed "s/@vitejs\/plugin-vue@//g"

############################
### resources/js/App.vue ###
############################

file_app_vue='resources/js/App.vue'

echo "CREATE FILE '$file_app_vue':"

touch resources/js/App.vue

echo "<script setup>"      > $file_app_vue
echo "</script>"          >> $file_app_vue
echo "<template>"         >> $file_app_vue
echo "    hello from Vue" >> $file_app_vue
echo "</template>"        >> $file_app_vue
echo "<script>"           >> $file_app_vue
echo "</script>"          >> $file_app_vue

###########################
### resources/js/app.js ###
###########################

file_app_js='resources/js/app.js'

echo "REPLACE FILE '$file_app_js':"

echo "import './bootstrap.mjs';"         > $file_app_js
echo "import { createApp } from 'vue';" >> $file_app_js
echo "import App from './App.vue';"     >> $file_app_js
echo "const app = createApp(App);"      >> $file_app_js
echo "app.mount('#app');"               >> $file_app_js

#########################################
### resources/views/welcome.blade.php ###
#########################################

file_welcome='resources/views/welcome.blade.php'

echo "REPLACE FILE '$file_welcome':"

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>"                                               > $file_welcome
echo "<head>"                                                       >> $file_welcome
echo "    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"                                 >> $file_welcome
echo "    <title>Laravel Vue</title>"                               >> $file_welcome
echo "    <script src=\"{{ asset('js/app.js') }}\" defer></script>" >> $file_welcome
echo "</head>"                                                      >> $file_welcome
echo "<body>"                                                       >> $file_welcome
echo "    <div id=\"app\">"                                         >> $file_welcome
echo "        <hello-vue />"                                        >> $file_welcome
echo "    </div>"                                                   >> $file_welcome
echo "</body>"                                                      >> $file_welcome
echo "</html>"                                                      >> $file_welcome

##################################
### resources/js/bootstrap.mjs ###
##################################

echo "RENAME FILE 'resources/js/bootstrap.js':"
mv resources/js/bootstrap.js resources/js/bootstrap.mjs

#######################
### webpack.mix.cjs ###
#######################

file_webpack='webpack.mix.cjs'

echo "CREATE FILE '$file_webpack':"

touch $file_webpack

echo "const mix = require('laravel-mix');"                         > $file_webpack
echo "const webpack = require('webpack');"                        >> $file_webpack
echo "mix.webpackConfig ({"                                       >> $file_webpack
echo "    plugins: ["                                             >> $file_webpack
echo "        new webpack.DefinePlugin({"                         >> $file_webpack
echo "            __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__: false" >> $file_webpack
echo "        }),"                                                >> $file_webpack
echo "    ],"                                                     >> $file_webpack
echo "})"                                                         >> $file_webpack
echo "mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')"                 >> $file_webpack
echo "    .vue({"                                                 >> $file_webpack
echo "        version: 3,"                                        >> $file_webpack
echo "        options: {"                                         >> $file_webpack
echo "            compilerOptions: {"                             >> $file_webpack
echo "                isCustomElement: (tag) => ["                >> $file_webpack
echo "                    'x-custom-tag',"                        >> $file_webpack
echo "                ].includes(tag),"                           >> $file_webpack
echo "            }"                                              >> $file_webpack
echo "        }"                                                  >> $file_webpack
echo "    }).postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', []);" >> $file_webpack

######################
### vite.config.js ###
######################

file_vite_config='vite.config.js'

echo "REPLACE FILE '$file_vite_config':"

echo "import { defineConfig } from 'vite';"                                  > $file_vite_config
echo "import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';"                           >> $file_vite_config
echo "import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';"                                >> $file_vite_config
echo "export default defineConfig({"                                        >> $file_vite_config
echo "    plugins: ["                                                       >> $file_vite_config
echo "        vue(),"                                                       >> $file_vite_config
echo "        laravel({"                                                    >> $file_vite_config
echo "            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js']," >> $file_vite_config
echo "            refresh: true,"                                           >> $file_vite_config
echo "        }),"                                                          >> $file_vite_config
echo "    ]"                                                                >> $file_vite_config
echo "});"                                                                  >> $file_vite_config

#####################
### final actions ###
#####################

echo "COMMAND 'npm run build':" && npm run build
echo "COMMAND 'npx mix':"       && npx mix
```

p.s. From the author and developer of min-CMS/CMF Effcore.